# https to http for an old program

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

(sorry, bad english)

I have an old software, that call webpages.
But it cannot call https-pages, only http.
My nginx.conf for nginx:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {worker_connections  1024;}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #------------------
    # from me:
    server {
       server_name localhost; listen 30001;
       set $x https://www.example1.com/downloads;
       location / { proxy_pass $x; }
    }
    server {
       server_name localhost; listen 30002;
       set $x https://www.example2.com/news;
       location / { proxy_pass $x; }
    }
    ...
    #------------------

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {root html;}
    }
}
```

Then in the software I can use:

```
http://localhost:30001  ->  calls https://www.example1.com/downloads
http://localhost:30002  ->  calls https://www.example2.com/news
```

Disadvantage:
I must write a server{}-Block for EVERY https-webpage into the nginx.conf.

Is ther a way to do https->http for ALL https-webpages?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use https for everything instead of channeling individual links? Or a way to generalize your statement so it applies to all throughput?

Comment: No chance to use https, only http is allowed. "generalize your statement so it applies to all throughput?" That is what I ask for :)

Comment: Ah right, you did. Maybe the professional server stack exchange can help? Those guys do far more complex things on a daily basis.